# Post using curl and HTTP Requester generates different dictionaries

Tags: python, django, curl

I am using django-oauth2-provider to generate access tokens. Problem is that different POST requests are getting forged when using curl and browser based HTTP requester

This is what is forged when using curl:

```
{u'username': [u'admin'], u'client_secret':[u'50c96e6351c623b271a61e197a22de9fcdbfa'], u'password': [u'admin'], u'grant_type': [u'password'], u'client_id': [u'7f1ad1344d6d0a0e7b44']}
```

and this is what is formed when using the browser based HTTP Requester

```
{u"{'grant_type': 'password','client_id': 7f1ad1344d6d0a0e7b44,'client_secret': 50c96e6351c623b271a61e197a22de9fcdbfa,'username': admin,'password': admin}": [u'']}
```

The first one works fine, the second one obviously does not. What could be going wrong in the second case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was entering JSON into the requester:

```
{'grant_type': 'password','client_id': 7f1ad1344d6d0a0e7b44,'client_secret': 50c96e6351c623b271a61e197a22de9fcdbfa,'username': admin,'password': admin}
```

Since I was supposed to send it as

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

it had to be sent as

```
client_id=7f1ad1344d6d0a0e7b44&client_secret=50c96e6351c623b271a61e197a22de9fcdbfa&grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin
```